# Integral with Tanh: $\int_{0}^{b} \tanh(x)/x \mathrm{d} x$ . What would be the solution when 'b' does not tends to infinity though a large one?

Tags: calculus

two integrals that got my attention because I really don't know how to solve them. They are a solution to the CDW equation below critical temperature of a 1D strongly correlated electron-phonon system. The second one  is used in the theory of superconductivity, while the first is a more complex variation in lower dimensions. I know the result for the second one, but without the whole calculus, it is meaningless.

$$ \int_0^b \frac{\tanh(c(x^2-b^2))}{x-b}\mathrm{d}x $$

$$ \int_0^b \frac{\tanh(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x \approx \ln\frac{4e^\gamma b}{\pi} \text{as} \ b \to \infty$$
where $\gamma = 0.57721...$ is Euler's constant

Comment: If you had edited your MO question with your motivation, I'm sure it would have been reopened. Nevertheless, your second result is wrong; differentiating the right-hand side does not give the integrand.

Comment: you are right J.M. I've should have put $\approx$ sign in the second integral, but then again when I calculate it numerically  it agrees perfectly..

Comment: What exactly is the domain of validity for your $b$ ? I have apparently made the implicit assumption that $b\in\mathbb{R}$, but there will have to be something special about your $b$ for "when I calculate it numerically it agrees perfectly" to be true.

Comment: @ J.M.: agreed: integrating tanh(x)/x from 0 to 1 yields approximately 0.91. The natural logarithm of $4e^{\gamma}/(\pi)$ is about 0.82. So at least for b=1, the second equality isn't correct.

Comment: Also, doing a quick inverse lookup on Wolfram Alpha's value for the integral from 0 to 1 yields nothing that looks remotely close, so I'm skeptical of any clean closed-form solution.

Comment: @J.M.: A quick plot shows that $\int_0^b \frac{\tanh(x)}{x}dx \approx \ln \frac{4 e^\gamma b}{\pi}$ for large $b$.  Logarithmic growth makes sense since for large $x$, $\tanh x \approx 1$.

Comment: @Nate: I know that, what I was telling zoran was that it is disingenuous to claim equality. since I do know for a fact that $\frac{\tanh{x}}{x}$ (& by extension, $\frac{\tan{x}}{x}$). do not admit integrals representable as elementary functions. (I would speculate that a (multivariate?) hypergeometric function is needed (the hyperbolic tangent after all is expressible as a hypergeometric function), but I do not have the stomach for manipulations).

Comment: Otherwise, that indeed is a useful asymptotic result.

Comment: @Mo: you sure about the re-titling? He's actually asking about two integrals, not just one...

Comment: @J.M: The first can be gotten from the second very easily. In any case, I hope the title is more descriptive than earlier.

Comment: Please see Fetter,Walecka *Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems* P447 and Appendix A

Answer (score 13):

The constant $C$ given in Aryabhata's answer, as suspected, is exactly

$$\gamma + \log \frac{4}{\pi},$$

which, together with Aryabhata's answer, nicely rounds off the second part of this question.

Since $ \text{sech} x = 2(e^{-x} – e^{-3x} + e^{-5x} + \cdots ) \qquad (1)$ we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\tanh x}{x}\mathrm dx =
2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh x}{x}(e^{-x} – e^{-3x} + e^{-5x} + \cdots )\mathrm dx$$

Now

$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh x}{x} e^{-x}\mathrm dx = - \mathrm{Ei}(-2) + \gamma + \log 2$$
$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh x}{x} e^{-3x}\mathrm dx = - \mathrm{Ei}(-4) + \mathrm{Ei}(-2) + \log 2$$
$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh x}{x} e^{-5x}\mathrm dx = - \mathrm{Ei}(-6) + \mathrm{Ei}(-4) + \log (3/2)$$
$$2\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh x}{x} e^{-7x}\mathrm dx = - \mathrm{Ei}(-8) + \mathrm{Ei}(-6) + \log (4/3)$$

and so on, where $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ is the [exponential integral.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)

Thus, interchanging the order of summation, summing and using [Wallis's product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)
we obtain
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\tanh x}{x}\mathrm dx = \gamma + \log \frac{4}{\pi}
-2\mathrm{Ei}(-2)+2\mathrm{Ei}(-4)-2\mathrm{Ei}(-6) + \cdots. \qquad (2)$$

Using $(1)$ for $\mathrm{sech} x$ we also have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{x(e^{2/x}+1) }\mathrm dx = 2 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\mathrm dx$$
$$=  \int_1^\infty \frac{\text{sech} x}{x} e^{-x}\mathrm dx
= 2  \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-2x}}{x} - \frac{e^{-4x}}{x} + \frac{e^{-6x}}{x} - \cdots\mathrm dx $$
$$=  -2\mathrm{Ei}(-2)+2\mathrm{Ei}(-4)-2\mathrm{Ei}(-6) + \cdots.$$

And so the result follows from $(2).$

Answer (score 7):

I get

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{b}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \approx C + \log b$$

where

$$\displaystyle C = \int_{0}^{1}(\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} -\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2/x}+1)} \ )\text{dx} = 0.81878\dots$$

We have $\displaystyle \log \frac{4e^{\gamma}}{\pi} = 0.81878\dots$, <strike>so your formula could be right!</strike>  It is in fact correct.

See Derek's excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/integral-with-tanh-int-0b-tanhx-x/11358#11358).

---

**Derivation**

We have $\displaystyle \dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} = \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}$

Assuming $b > 1$,

$$\displaystyle f(b) = \int_{0}^{b}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \ \text{dx} = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \ \text{dx}  + \int_{1}^{b} (\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)})\ \text{dx}$$

$$\displaystyle f(b) =  \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \ \text{dx}  + \log b - \int_{1}^{b}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx}$$

Now
$$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{b}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx} = \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx} - \int_{b}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx}$$

Subsitute $t = \dfrac{1}{x}$ in the first integral, we get

$$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx} = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2}{t(e^{2/t}+1)}\ \text{dt}$$

Thus

$$\displaystyle f(b) =  \int_{0}^{1}(\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} -\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2/x}+1)} \ )\text{dx}  + \log b + \int_{b}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx}$$

Now, as $\displaystyle b \to \infty$, $\displaystyle \int_{b}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2x}+1)}\ \text{dx} \to 0$

Thus we have that,

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{b}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \approx \log b + \int_{0}^{1}(\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} -\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2/x}+1)} \ )\text{dx} $$

Thus

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{b}\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} \approx C + \log b$$

where

$$\displaystyle C = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{\tanh(x)}{x} -\dfrac{2}{x(e^{2/x}+1)} \ \right)\text{dx} = 0.81878\dots$$

Comment: I thought that as well, but you just obtain the same integral as a result. Considering that the Euler-Mascheroni constant is involved, I suspect the answer is non-trivial. Maybe using Laplace-transforms in some way could help.

Comment: @Rasko: You are right. I had an extra b, which cancelled the b in the denominator after integrating, giving a different integral...

Comment: The comments of Raskolnikov (and my response) are applicable to the first version of my answer.

Comment: @Moron WolframAlpha gives the value of $C$ as 0.81878 and not 0.864227, so it looks like the formula is correct. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_0^1+(+(\tanh+x)/x+-+2/(x(e^(2/x)+%2B+1))+)dx

Comment: My link didn't post correctly, but never mind, recheck how you obtained that figure of 0.864227.

Comment: @Derek: I used wolfram Alpha too! You are right though! I must have made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ large, $\tanh x$ is very close to $1$. Therefore for large $b$, $$\int_0^b \frac{\tanh x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \approx C + \int^b \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = C' + \log b.$$ You can prove it rigorously and obtain a nice error bound if you wish. Your post indicates a specific value of $C'$, but for large $b$, any two "close" constants $C_1,C_2$ will satisfy $$\log b + C_1 \approx \log b + C_2,$$ so probably $\gamma + \log (4/\pi)$ has no significance other than being a number close to $C'$ and having a nice form.

If we do the estimation rigorously, we will probably find out that $C'$ is well defined (i.e. the error in the first $\approx$ is $o(b)$), and then one can ask for its value. It probably has no nice closed form.

EDIT: In fact $\gamma + \log (4/\pi)$ is the correct constant, as shown in Derek's answer.