# Asymptotic expression of $\int_{- D}^{D} \frac{\text{tanh}(\xi)}{\xi -\omega}\mathrm{d}\xi$

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, cauchy-principal-value

How to derive the following asymptotic expression ($|\omega| \ll D $)?

$$P.V.\int_{- D}^{D} d\xi \frac{\tanh(\beta \xi)}{\xi -\omega} \approx 2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{\omega^2+T^2}}\right),\ \ \  \beta =1/T,\ \  \omega, T \rightarrow 0.$$

Two limiting cases:

1) $\omega=0, \lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\int_{- D}^{D} d\xi \frac{\text{tanh}(\beta \xi)}{\xi} \approx 2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{T}\right) + C \approx 2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{T}\right)$;

2) $T=0, \lim_{\omega \rightarrow 0} \int_{- D}^{D} d\xi \frac{\theta(\xi)-\theta( -\xi)}{\xi -\omega} \approx 2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{\omega}\right).$

Some write $2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{\text{max}(\omega, T)}\right)$ instead of $ 2  \ln\left(\frac{D}{\sqrt{\omega^2+T^2}}\right).$

Can anyone elaborate Jack's answer? Thank you.

[Reference.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/integral-with-tanh-int-0b-tanhx-x-mathrmd-x)

Actually, this is an important expression from physics, which is directly related to the [Kondo problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kondo_effect), the divergence at the third order of perturbation theory.

Comment: Have you tried to replace $tanh(\xi)$ by its value at the pole?

Comment: What does $P$ mean before the integral? Is $\omega$ real?

Comment: i have some doubts about the result... can someone confirm that it is correct? Numerical caluclations doesn't look correct.

Comment: Thank all you guys for helping me. I just updated the post in order not to waste your precious time. Should I make any mistakes, please feel free to point it out.

Comment: ah now eveytthing makes sense...

Answer (score 7):

We may just exploit the identity:
$$\tanh x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8x}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2+4x^2}\tag{1}$$
that comes from the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the (hyperbolic) cosine function:
$$\cosh x = \prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right).\tag{2}$$
After that, through:
$$ \int_{A}^{B}\frac{8\,dx}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2+4x^2}=\left.\frac{4}{(2n+1)\pi}\,\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)\right|_{A}^{B} \tag{3}$$
we have everything we need to estimate our integrals, through:
$$\forall x\geq 0,\qquad \arctan(x)<\frac{\pi x}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}<\min\left(x,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).\tag{4}$$
The sharper inequality is the Shafer-Fink inequality (see [my note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753), for instance).

In other terms, $(1)$ just gives that $\frac{\tanh z}{z}$ is a series of [Lorentzian functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html), pretty easy to estimate.